# How to serialize custom data from database?

Tags: c#, database, serialization

I've a table like this :

```
ID  Name        Key     Value
1   Mydata1     Mail        myval1
1   Mydata1     Name        myval2
1   Mydata1     Nick        myval3
1   Yourdata    key2        myval4
```

and a class like this :

```
[Serializable]
public class Mydata
{
    public string Mail{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Nick{get;set;}
}
```

I extract from my Table data 
where Name = 'MyData1' in a list.

How To serialize this data in my class.
Thanks!

Comment: When you say serialize do you mean how to do you query your database to populate your Mydata object?

Comment: are you asking "how do I transpose a SQL table?"

Answer (score 1):

You should look into LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, NHibernate, etc. These are OR Mappers, or Object/Relational Mappers. They are designed to query your database for you, and return serialized objects from your domain. They can greatly reduce the amount of effort it takes to build an application with objects that are persisted to and retrieved from a database server.

Note that Linq to SQL required SQL Server, while the other two can be used with any database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your class already, you are looking for "POCO" support in an ORM.

E.g. Entities Framework v4 does this. See [here for details](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx). I understand nHibernate has this support today.

Alternatively in your data access layer, you can do the conversion in your data access layer (DTO == [Data Transfer Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)) using a data reader:

```
var rs = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
var results = new List<MyDto>();
while (rs.Read()) {
  results.Add(new MyDto {
    Id = rs.ReadInt("Id"),
    Name = rs.ReadString("Name"),
    ...
  };
}
```

Using LINQ to SQL:

```
using (var dc = MyDataContext()) {
  var results = from d in dc.MyDataType
                select new MyDto {
                  Id = d.Id,
                  Name = d.Name,
                  ...
                };
}
```

However I tend to add a method to customise the generated entity with a helper method to perform the mapping (which helps avoid repeating the property copy code for each query).